# Получить HWND по имеющемуся HANDLE процесса c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Прошу помочь с данным вопросом, поскольку не могу найти однозначного ответа. Запускаю окно браузера функцией CreateProcessA(), после чего хочу всячески взаимодействовать с этим окном. Создав процесс, я получил его ProcessId, ThreadId и HANDLE. так каким же образом мне получить сам дескриптор окна?

Comment: `HWND Handle = FindWindow(NULL, "MyTitle");`

Comment: @DrMcSheen, эту функцию я знаю, но что если я, не знаю ни заголовка, ни класса. Хотел бы нати способ сделать с помощью данных, которые мне уже известны.

Comment: Заголовок можно задать в STARTUPINFO при создании процесса

Comment: @DrMcSheen Да, спасибо, очень полезная информация, буду этим пользоваться в дальнейшем, однако с окном браузера это не сработало

Answer (score 0):

Используйте SPY++ - чтобы посмотреть "class name" - вашего окна браузера.
А потом уже по имени класса окна через функцию FindWindow() - получайте HWND.

Но, конечно - этот метод актуален, если только Вам нужно сделать - это конкретно для браузера или запускаемого Вами окна, имя класса, которого можно посмотреть заранее.

PS:

> WinMain_Console:15
>
> WinMain_Console - Microsoft Visual Studio:41
>
> Lofi Ghostie - YouTube - Google Chrome:38
>
> OpenGL Tutorial 1 - Window - YouTube - Яндекс.Браузер:53
>
> WinMain_Console:15
>
> Почта:5
>
> Добавить учетную запись:23
>
> Почта:5
>
> Microsoft Text Input Application:32
>
> Program Manager:15
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ConsoleWindowClass:18
>
> HwndWrapper[DefaultDomain;;ea1e768d-f160-40c7-980f-f4851b7cfe00]:64
>
> Chrome_WidgetWin_1:18
>
> YandexBrowser_WidgetWin_1:25
>
> XLMAIN:6
>
> HwndWrapper[DefaultDomain;;51c1ee7a-0173-4532-a4e1-4742864b8e4e]:64
>
> Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow:26
>
> ApplicationFrameWindow:22
>
> ApplicationFrameWindow:22
>
> Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow:26
>
> Progman:7

Comment: Насколько я понял, в Windows по умолчанию отсутствует возможность такого рода взаимодействия с окном браузера. его нужно запускать с определенными ключами запуска. Не знаете, где можно найти, какие именно ключи нужны для того же Firefox или IExplorer?

Comment: @kiwi80085, а такого рода взаимодействия - это какое именно ?

Comment: Мне нужен был HWND для установки положения и размеров окна с помощью функции SetWindowPos( ). Однако, запустив тот же хром по умолчанию, в SPY++ я не нашел ни названия класса, ни заголовка. лишь добавив необходимые ключи запуска я достиг нужного результата. Все еще надеюсь на какой-нибудь универсальный метод))

Comment: @kiwi80085, единственно, что могу еще "посоветовать", использовать EnumWindows() и получить ВСЕ HWND окон запущенных на рабочем столе + информацию о имени класса этого HWND и имена окна и как то из этого всего списка HWND, Class name и windows name - понять, что это именно браузер хром. Так себе конечно метод, но другого не знаю к сожалению :)

Comment: Спасибо) Буду дальше искать

Comment: @kiwi80085, кстати ради любопытства запустил EnumWindows() и вот, что он мне выдал. (см. в ответе, так как в комментах неудобно естественно) - То есть окно Хрома и Яндекс браузера отследить не проблема. По крайней мере у меня.